# Cheapest way to cast spells with sword and (heavy) shield?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, dnd-3.5e, shield

Suppose a spellcaster wishes to use a heavy shield, or even a heavier shield like a tower shield. Divine, so arcane spell failure doesn’t apply, but they are using a weapon. Since heavy (and heavier) shields use the hand, you cannot simply pass the weapon into your other hand like you could with a light shield (and certainly cannot perform somatic gestures with the shield hand, as you could with a buckler).

*Complete Mage* has the Somatic Weaponry feat that gets around this, but a feat seems like an awful lot to expend for what amounts to a +1 to +3 additional shield bonus to AC. Particularly considering that characters with two-handed weapons, already better off, don’t have to do anything at all; they can just let go of the weapon and cast the spell.

Anything that requires a non-free action in combat is useless, so dropping or sheathing the weapon is not a good answer (unless you can somehow cheaply make these approaches free actions, but I think that is impossible). But long-term buff spells (especially those that are wand-able), magic items, mundane item alterations, etc. are all great. Particularly efficient dips *might* be ok, especially if it’s just one level that is also doing other things for you (double particularly if it progresses spellcasting). Feats that allow this *and also* do other things are good, too.

Please cite sources, and in particular note any materials coming from third-party sources. Material must have been published for D&D 3.5e and/or Pathfinder to be considered.

Comment: Before anyone thinks about it (and it's probably the very first thing to come to mind), **Weapon Cords** were errata'ed to be a Move Action (down from a *swift*).

Comment: @ShadowKras Ultimately, the way the question’s currently worded, even pre-errata weapon cords wouldn’t qualify, since they require a non-free action (i.e. a swift). Also, they’re dumb, though nerfing them was even dumber, and the reasoning for the nerf was just *the* dumbest thing.

Comment: pre-errata, you could drop the weapon as a free, and grab it back as swift, which was plenty for *most* characters.

Comment: @ShadowKras Yes, I realize that: what I am saying is that while that may have been plenty for “most characters”[citation needed], it wouldn’t be good enough *here*.

Comment: I'd argue that even the feat Somatic Weaponry is insufficient for this divine caster: even if she has that feat, for many spells that divine caster must still manipulate her divine focus, a task that's likely supposed to occupy the hand that would normally be satisfying the somatic components. In other words, don't forget the armor and shield extra sanctified (*Du* 30, 34) (50 gp; 0 lbs.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Glove of the master strategist:** (3.600 gp, Ghostwalk pg 71). As a free action, store shield inside the glove or make it appear in your hand. It depends on the table if a retrieved shield is considered donned or simply held when it gets out of the glove. As an overpriced alternative, [Glove of storing](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#gloveofStoring) has the same effect.

**Arms of the Naga:** (56.000 gp, Savage Species pg 55). Two extra arms that can carry your shield for you, but they are expensive.

**Girallon's blessing:** Spell from the spell compendium that gets you two extra arms. It's a 3rd level spell, so it is wand-able if you do not mind spending 11250 gp on a wand. Decent duration too (10 minutes/level).

I would also mention **[Shielded mage](http://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Shielded%20Mage)** feat, from Pathfinder. It's a poor candidate because it has [Shield focus](http://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Shield%20Focus) as prerequisite, costing two feats for the same effect as Somatic Weaponry plus a measly +1AC. The only redeeming point is that you can have it as early as level at level 1 if you don't mind a 1 level dip in fighter (which you need anyway if you ever want to use a tower shield).

Comment: While the *gloves of storing* are traditional, in *3.5* even better is the *glove of the master strategist* (*Gh* 71) (3,600 gp; 0 lbs.), a straight improvement over the *gloves* at less than half the price.

Comment: If anybody else but me wondered, what "Gh" means: "Ghostwalk" supplement.

Comment: How come these gloves can be cheaper than *gloves of storing*?

Comment: @Giorin In 3.0e, *gloves of storing* cost a lot, lot less. *Ghostwalk* was originally printed for 3.0, and so *gloves of the master strategist* were priced based on the 3.0e price. In 3.5e, the price of the *gloves of storing* was massively, unreasonably increased. *Ghostwalk* then received an update to 3.5e, but the price of the *gloves of the master strategist* did not change. It’s a bizarre situation that *gloves of the master strategist* are strictly superior to *gloves of storing* yet cost barely a third what *gloves of storing* cost, but few people “fix” it because 10k is way overpriced.

Answer (score 1):

## Ask whether you can gesture with a holy symbol.

Depending on how they're read, the spellcasting rules may allow somatic components to be performed using a hand that's also simultaneously fulfilling the spell's material, focus, or divine focus components. In my experience, there's a fairly strong player consensus in favor of this interpretation, but I don't believe it's explicitly spelled out in the rules of either 3.5 or Pathfinder (the most "official" answer I've found on the matter is [Skip Williams' support for this interpretation in *Rules of the Game*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20040810a), and that's [far from an authoritative source](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60044/what-is-wrong-with-the-dd-3-5-faq)). Considering the ambiguity, it's worth asking for your DM's ruling on whether you can use a hand holding a divine focus to perform somatic components.

If that's permitted, some much less expensive options open up. A Sanctified Shield (Dungeonscape pg 34) costs only an extra 50 gp, while a [Reliquary Weapon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/create-reliquary-arms-and-shields/) will cost 250 gp. Either one will allow you to access a divine focus (and, by extension, somatic components) while still wielding your weapon and shield.

However, note that even with a favorable reading of the somatic/divine focus rules, this method will only work for spells that include a divine focus component. Spells that include somatic components without a divine focus requirement (e.g. *bestow curse*) will still require a free hand.